# Groovy class overridden constructor, why MissingMethodException?

Tags: groovy

I have the following class:

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class PythonBuild {
    def basePath
    def branchName

    PythonBuild(String basePath, String branchName) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

when I instantiate it:

```
master = PythonBuild('Python-Backend/+MASTER/', 'master')
```

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
Script1.PythonBuild() is applicable for argument types:
(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [Python-Backend/+MASTER/, master]
```

This error makes no sense to me since, as far as I can tell, the constructor is defined as taking two strings and I am passing two strings.

I am new to Groovy and have got this far by copying examples. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `Newify` is not inherited. Could you please check it? Annotate `PythonBuild` with `Newify`?

Comment: Should not it be with keyword `new` while initiating new class `master = new PythonBuild('Python-Backend/+MASTER/', 'master')`

Comment: @mst is right, you're just missing the `new` infront of `PythonBuild` when trying to call the constructor...  Voting to close this as a simple typographic error

Comment: @tim_yates, is that really a typo or a case with `Newify`?

Comment: @Opal where does `Newify` come into it?

Comment: Constructing objects in python is done without `new` - exactly in the way  OP used it. Since class name is `PythonBuild` I infer it may be `Newify` related question. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @tim_yates it's not a typographic error, I didn't realise the keyword was required.  And to be honest the error message from Groovy is not very helpful... though I think I understand now that is was looking for a `static` method to call rather than the constructor (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` keyword missed, while invoking constructor.

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class PythonBuild {    
    def basePath     
    def branchName     
    def PythonBuild(String basePath, String branchName) { } 
}


def master = new PythonBuild('Python-Backend/+MASTER/', 'master')


println(master)
```